# Making the "student" less prominent

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I have been in the industry for >15years but I am still enrolled in university.

If I tick the "I am currently a student" box, the "student" is showing up directly below my name. This makes my profile look really unattractive for senior positions.
So I currently have opted for not ticking the "I am currently a student" box and instead mentioned in the free text that I am still a student.

So my wishlist item: make it possible not to display the "student" status so prominently.

Or do you guys have some other ideas how to solve this dilemma?

Comment: What do you mean "enrolled in university"? If you chose academic career, it can hardly be considered being a student to begin with.

Comment: No, not academic career; more like temporary job-out.